# All integers from 1 to 73 are recorded in a sequence such that each number

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, contest-math, integers

All integers from 1 to 73 are recorded in a sequence such that each number (from the second onwards) divides the sum of all previous numbers.

c) What numbers can be in the third place and why?

---

This question is from [a Russian contest](http://school2-lgov.ru/images/DOCS/Matematika_30_var_tip_zad_i_800_ch.pdf). See page 11, question C6. Тhis is the final task of one of the training test to prepare for the USE in Russia. The complexity of this task traditionally corresponds to the level of a good math Olympiad.

**Previous questions in this problem (more obvious):**

a) Could the last number be 5?

b) What numbers could be last?

*In the b) it's hard enough to build an example for 1 in last place.*

*The problem is that we cannot use a computer. ) 240 minutes was given for solution and careful recording of all 20 tasks. Tools - pen and paper.*

Comment: Have you tried with smaller odd numbers/primes to see if you can spot any pattern. What happens with $5$? With $7$?

Comment: @Mark Bennet Thank for supporting me. ) Unfortunately, the situation for 9, 13, 15, 20+ and other sequence lengths is different. (

Comment: @JoeBradley Are you sure such a sequence exists? Which Math Olympia had this as a problem? They usually publish their solutions.

Comment: @john-douma I would be glad if this task had been given at any concrete competition. ) Тhis is the final task of one of the training test to prepare for the USE in Russia. The complexity of this task traditionally corresponds to the level of a good math Olympiad. If you like I can provide a link to this test (in Russian of course). There's only answer there, no solution.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87717/discussion-on-question-by-joe-bradley-all-integers-from-1-to-73-are-recorded-in).

Comment: I like this question! Don't let the killjoys put you off, Joe. Having said that, I can't for the life of me see how to solve it.

Comment: @TonyK ) Thanks, Tony.

Comment: This question is autodeleted due to its low score. The reason why it had a low score is that initially it was phrased without much context (see the linked to chat.) The precedence you give is on the one hand old and on the other hand contains more input from the poster.

Comment: It appears to me that the question contains three parts.  Typically, in such cases the first parts of a question can help to provide intuition for answering later parts.  My Russian is a bit rusty---as I read it, part (a) is "Could the last number be 5?"  and part (b) is "What numbers could be last?"  I would edit these into the question, but I am not certain of my translation.

Comment: Additionally, you say that the problem is "different" when we choose 7 or 9 or 20.  I think that this is obviously true.  However, it is often possible to gain intuition on a big problem by first solving a smaller problem.  Can you explain why you think that these smaller cases are useless?

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen Ok, thanks.

Comment: @Xander Henderson You have correctly translated everything. ) I have information about the answer (for the sequence of ANY length), which I believe. An advanced programmer can quickly test it.

Comment: @Xander Henderson I want to say that the answer for 9, 13, 15 and 20+ is THE SAME.

Comment: For 3 and 5 - the second answer,
for 4  - the third answer,
for 6 - the forth,

Comment: for 7 - the fifth,
for 8 - sixth,
for 10 and 11 - seventh,
for 12 - eighth,
for 14 - ninth,
for 16 and 17 - tenth,
for 19 and 19 - eleventh.

Comment: for 18 and 19 of course

Comment: @rschwieb Not so dramatically. ))) I'm not laughing at you, of course. You will understand everything by reading the corresponding branch on the metasite. This is a natural consequence of the fact that I have to fulfill various personal wishes (although I even agree with some) of some users. In fact, the problem has three points. I was interested in the THIRD. He stayed higher.

Comment: @joe I see now, thanks.

Comment: Is that the answer, on page 181 of the Russian link? Top of the page, C6?

Comment: Yes. Of course.

Comment: And, please, Joe, what does it say? I mean, in English, so I can understand it.

Comment: A! ) In third place can be any number. 1-73.

Comment: Thanks, Joe. I find that very surprising. E.g., for $43$ to be the third number, the ordering must start $42,1,43,2$ and I'm surprised there's enough flexibility to continue that all the way to the end.

Comment: See [this meta thread](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29914/11619) for a discussion about the issues in this question. <- Posting the link here, because IMHO it is misplaced in the question body.

Answer (score 3):

"All integers from 1 to 73 are recorded in a sequence such that each number (from the second onwards) divides the sum of all previous numbers."

Here is such a sequence, obtained by hand:

72 2 37 3 38 4 39 5 40 6 41 7 42 8 43 9 44 10 45 11 46 12 47 13 48 14 49 15 50 16 51 17 52 18 53 19 54 20 55 21 56 22 57 23 58 24 59 25 60 26 61 27 62 28 63 29 64 30 65 31 66 32 67 33 68 34 69 35 70 36 71 1 73

I trust the pattern is clear, and clearly works for all $n$ (though there are tiny differences depending on the parity of $n$).

Comment: Is this the answer? Of course no. ) Try this pattern for example for 1 in the last place.

Comment: It is what it is, Joe: it shows that for every positive integer $n$, you can order the integers $1,\dots,n$ so that each divides the sum of all the ones before it. It's a point no one addressed, and it seems nice to know. Also, it shows that one can work on the problem without a computer, which gives some hope for answering your questions without using a computer. Also, it does give you $1$ in the last place  for even $n$.

Comment: Did not quite understand your last sentence. About 1.

Comment: If you just lop off the $73$ at the end, my example gives an ordering for $n=72$, with $1$ as the last term. And the pattern works for all even $n$. This is in response to your "it's hard enough to build an example for 1 in last place."

Comment: But I spoke about n=73, not 72.

Comment: Not everything is about you, Joe. I'm making some contributions to knowledge about the general question of ordering $1,\dots,n$ so each divides the sum of all those preceding. If you can't see a way to apply it to the specific problem that brought you here, well, life is like that.

Comment: Maybe I do not see, alas. Maybe my (and Google's) English does not allow me to convey all the necessary nuances, but you answered with an example with n = 72 to my phrase, which referred to a specific task with a specific (other) n.

Comment: @Joe Bradley: an example of *any* sequence would have been a good addition to the original question.  A method to create such sequences by hand is certainly progress, even if it doesn't answer then entire question yet.

Comment: @Carl, all I claim to do is, for every $n$, find one ordering of $1,\dots,n$ such that each number divides the sum of all those preceding. If $n=2m$ is even, it goes $2m,2,m+1,3,m+2,\dots,n-2,m,n-1,1$; if $n=2m+1$ is odd, it goes $2m,2,m+1,3,m+2,\dots,n-3,m,n-2,1,n$.

Comment: I was taught, Joe, that if I couldn't solve a problem, I should look for a similar or related problem which I could solve, and then solve that, in the hopes that what I was able to do would give someone the clue she needed to solve, or make progress on, the original problem. That's what I've been doing here.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson: thanks, I see, I'm not sure what I was trying.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson I understand.

Answer (score 2):

This is not an answer, but too long for a comment. For people who are looking for some examples, here are a few I generated.

72 36 54 27 63 42 49  7 70 60
     48 66 33 57 38 19 39 65 13 26
     68 56 28 37 29 58 40 50 25 51
     34 20 69 23 64 32 16 44 22 15
      9  6 30 10  2 41 43 21  3 61
     31 62  8 24 14 35 59 12  4  5
     55 11 67 17 45 52 46 53 47 18
     71  1 73

72 36 27 45 60 48 32 64 24 68
     34 51 33 66 55 65 52 26 39 69
     46 44 22 49 23 50 40 62 42 56
     70 35 43 18 58 29 57 38  4 73
     25 10 31 61 16  8 19 15 67  1
      2 13  7 20 53 41 54 63 21 28
     14  3 17 71  5 30 12  6 47 11
     59  9 37

70 35 21 63 27 72 48 56 49  9
     50 25 15 60 40 64 44 68 51 17
     52 39 65 26 41  3 37 31 62 20
     45 29 58 24 59  5 10  1 71 22
     11 55 66 33 53 34  4 23 69 42
     47 43  6 30 28  7 61 12 46 14
     54 18 36  8 16 32 19 57 38 67
     13  2 73

60 30 45 27 54 72 48 56 49 63
     42 39 65 50 70 55 33 66 44 22
     18 36 58 38 57 21 29 43 15  9
     73 19 37 13 52 26 59  3 14 35
     47 12 71 25 20 10 61 31 62 32
     24 68 34  2 16 40 11 67 17 51
      6 28  5 53 46 69 23  7 41 64
      8  4  1

42  1 43  2 44 66 33 21 63 45
         72 54 27 57 38 32 64 22 11 67
         12 68 52 39 65 40 60 30 26 46
         69 23 58 48 36 41 37 14 56 29
         19  8 24  4 28 62 31 59 16  7
         49 20 55  5 34 61 35 70 10 50
         25 15  3 71 17 13 47 53  6 51
          9 18 73

Computation suggests that every number from 1 to 73 can be the third element of a sequence of the desired form, but this is not the case for other instances. For example, if we change 73 to 6, the numbers 1 and 3 are not possible as third elements of the sequence.

Comment: The last sequence was generated in pencil and paper, of course. ) Or not?

Comment: Of course not - just by computer.

Comment: It's right. That is the answer given in the Russian source. The problem is that we cannot use a computer. )

Comment: Can you generate one with third element 43, Carl?

Comment: @Gerry Myerson: no problem